# Android- do not split the context menu when splitted action bar used

Tags: android-actionbar, contextmenu, clipboard, android-edittext

I have an edit text and below that one button and action bar at the top and bottom in one of the screen in my application. after entering the the text in edit text when i long press on text in edit text cut copy context menu is disaplying at the top and botton (which is coming as overlay of current action bar), but here my problem is keyboard is hiding action bar , so i am not able to see the cut , copy menu. So what i want do as a solution is i want to display the cut copy context menu at the top only. but here it is displaying at the bottom because i am splitting the action bar . so how to stop splitting the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of onLongClickListenr on TextView i.e. when the user long clicks on the textview then only the keyboard will hide.

```
compose_MessageText.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(compose_MessageText.getWindowToken(),   0);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I forgot to mention , but i have used above code also.. same thing happened

Comment: which other listeners are you using? there might be a clash.

Comment: OnlongClicklistenr and on touch listener. while long clicking on text first on touch is calling and after that onlongclick is calling. i have tried with removing ontouch and used only on longclick then also same thing happened

Comment: your issue is that keyboard is shown and hide fast right?
This issue may be if you are testing on emulator or device response might be slow. try on different device. which device are you using?

Comment: i checkd in mobile and tablet same thing happend in both. what i want to do is wen i long click on text key board is hiding and showing and hidign this is happening.

Comment: finally i want to display whole context menu at the top only.so how to do that any idea

Comment: can you upload screenshots for a better understanding.